# Avoiding multiple rounds trips to the database for user permissions checking

Tags: postgresql, next.js, prisma

Is there any recommended approaches to improve the efficiency of checking if a particular user has the ability to read or update a record ?

I have this simplified schema (the actual one has a lot more than that. I have the team_owners table as a team can have multiple user owners and a user can also have multiple teams.

```
users
-----
id            
name

teams
-----
id 
name          

team_owners
-----------
team_id (fk teams.id)
user_id  (fk users.id)

games 
-----
id              
name    
team_id (fk teams.id)
```

To check if a user has the permissions to update a game, I have to run two queries along with a third to do any updating.

```
function dbCheckUserPermission(user_id, game_id) {
    // Fetch the game to get the team_id
    const game = await prisma.games.findUnique({
      where: {
        id: game_id,
      },
      select: {
        team_id: true,
      },
    });
  
    if (!game) {
      throw new Error("Game not found.");
    }
  
    // Check if the user is an owner of the team
    const isOwner = await prisma.team_owners.count({
      where: {
        user_id: user_id,
        team_id: game.team_id,
      },
    });
  
    // Return true if the user is an owner, false otherwise
    return isOwner > 0; 
}
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this as each query has added noticeable delay in my app ?

Comment: Try merging the two queries into a single query that directly checks if the user is an owner of the team associated with the game. Join the games and team_owners tables and filtering based on both user_id and game_id. Using a database feature like PostgreSQL's JOIN clause can significantly reduce the delay by minimizing the number of queries executed.